# Trying to get a difference in lists failing

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists:
list_a(tkt001 tkt002 tkt003 tkt004 tkt005 tkt006 tkt007 tkt008 tkt09 tkt010 tkt011 tkt012 tkt013 tkt014 tkt015 tkt016 tkt017 tkt018 tkt019)

list_b(tkt001 tkt003 tkt005 tkt007 tkt009 tkt010)

I have tried

```
print (sorted(set(list_a).difference(set(list_b))))
and
print(sorted(diff(list_a, list_b)))
```

Which failed to diff the lists.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example with your expectations and disappointments? Your question is not clear as it stands.

Comment: ``` import pandas as pd
import os

cases_dir = input("Please enter your files directory: ")
cases_list = os.listdir(cases_dir)

open_cases = pd.read_csv(r"cases.csv")
open_cases.columns = ["Number", "Product", "Subject", "Customer Contact", "Customer Name", "State", "Internal Status", "Follow up", "Case Priority", "Updated", "Updated by", "Days open"]
open_cases = open_cases[["Number"]]
print(open_cases, sep="\n")

list_a = cases_list
list_b = open_cases
x = (set(list_a)-set(list_b))
print(sorted(x)))``` I want only closed cases. I am getting all cases.

Comment: Your `list_a` comes from `cases_list`, which is a listing of all entities (files and folders) in `cases_dir`.  Since you're getting all cases, I guess your `list_b` must not be matching any of those entries.  I suggest you take a slice of `list_a` and `list_b` and manually study those items in both lists that you expect to be equal.

Comment: One of the things I have learned, is to use print() whenever you can for this kind of situation. If I compare the cases_dir output to the cases_list, I see 10 dir's that show up in both lists. I am not sure that the  (set(list_a)-set(list_b)) is working for me. If I reverse the order, I get 0 results. This gives me all the cases. Am i not normalizing the data to some form that makes for an equal comparison?

Comment: *Update* I meant to say: I am not sure that the (set(list_a)-set(list_b)) is working for me. This gives me all the cases. If I reverse the order, I get 0 results.  Am i not normalizing the data to some form that makes for an equal comparison?

Comment: You may want to `print(set(list_b))`.  I think you will find your culprit there.

Comment: And `print(set(list_a))` as well.  I have a hunch your problem is a mismatch of types between the two sets.  The directory listing returns strings, whereas your DataFrame is likely integers; if so, a string like `"1"` is not the same as the integer `1`.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation: print(type(cases_list)) returns <class 'list'>. Whereas, print(type(open_cases)) returns <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> So I need to equalize these to the same type so an apples to apples comparison will work!!!!

Comment: After trying for a few days to get the pandas dataframe converted to string, and failing all over the place, I changed up and put the strings into a dataframe. Now both are dataframes. So now I am moving on to trying to diff them to find the closed case folders. Thanks and take care!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is some way to extract the column of a DataFrame to a straight Python list. Someone with better knowledge of pandas may help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you created list_a and list_b.  But here is a simple example:

```
list_a = 'a b c'
list_b = 'b c d'

list_a = list_a.split(' ')
list_b = list_b.split(' ')

print(set(list_a).difference(set(list_b)))
{'a'}
```

Can you do `print(list_a)` and `print(list_b)`?